# Auto-Populate Dependent Picklist Values when selecting Controlling Field Using Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, dependent-picklist

I have 2 fields with picklist values one is Controlling Field and another is Dependent Field. picklist mapping was already done. Issue was when controlling field is selected , dependent field not auto populates. I wanted to achieve this by using apex.

I have a method 'getDependentPicklistValues' in another class returns dependent picklist values for controlling field in **Map<String,List<String**>> returntype.

Now I wanted to use this method to assign dependent picklist values when controlling fields were selected using apex triggers before insert and before update. I have implemented code but I am getting error as ' **Error: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Class.DependentPicklistValue.getDependentPicklistValues**' but when I execute the method in anonymous window I am getting both picklist values.

Can some one help me how to achieve this or is there any other way to auto-populate dependent picklist using apex

Code :

```
 public static void autoPopulateDefinitionPicklist(List<Object__c> newList, Map<Id,Object__c> oldMap){
        String controllingField = 'Controlling_Field__c';
        String dependentField = 'Dependent_Field__c';
        for(Object__c fieldUpdate: newList){
            Object__c oldfieldUpdate = oldMap.get(fieldUpdate.Id);
            if(oldfieldUpdate == null || oldfieldUpdate.Controlling_Field__c != 
                                         fieldUpdate.Controlling_Field__c){
        Map<String, List<String>> dependentPicklist = 
        DependentPicklistValue.getDependentPicklistValues('fieldUpdate.Controlling_Field__c');

                fieldUpdate.put(dependentField,dependentPicklist.get(String.valueOf(fieldUpdate.get(controllingField))));
           
                
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Do you have verified the good access to fields ? (you could set by Setup->Profil->Object parameters by example)

Comment: @arnaud thanks for responding. I have given proper object permissions and field permissions. I have modified the code but now I am getting new error as " FATAL_ERROR|System.SObjectException: Invalid field Access Issues for object

Comment: I think you could put without sharing in your Apex class (public without sharing class noSharing), in your logs, what is the line of the error ? Also, I see `getDependentPicklistValues('fieldUpdate.Controlling_Field__c');` Is it normal fieldUpdate.Controlling_Field__c is in cotes ? I would think to put `getDependentPicklistValues(Controlling_Field__c)` or `getDependentPicklistValues(fieldUpdate.Controlling_Field__c)`